# Using Get-AppxPackageManifest on Windows 8

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8

I tried running this command on a Windows 8 Powershell-

```
Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package Microsoft.ZuneVideo_1.0.927.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe | Select -Property *
```

This is the error I got-

```
Get-AppxPackageManifest : Cannot bind parameter 'Package'. Cannot convert the
"Microsoft.ZuneVideo_1.0.927.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe" value of type "System.String" to type
"Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AppxPackage".
At line:1 char:34
+ Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package Microsoft.ZuneVideo_1.0.927.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbw ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AppxPackageManifest], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.GetAppxPac
kageManifestCommand
```

I can directly pass the `PackageFullName` on Windows 10 but am unable to do so on Windows 8, as it does not seem to accept `System.String` type arguments. How exactly do I pass a  `Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AppxPackage` type argument to make `Get-AppxPackageManifest` work

Comment: You can't use the form `Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package "example package"` in Windows 8?

Comment: @RileyCarney Yes. I'm using Windows 8 Pro (64-bit) with Powershell version 3.0, if that helps.
`Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package` demands an argument of type `Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AppxPackage` which I'm not sure how to pass.

Comment: Hmm alright, I'll look more into the function when I'm off work. Does the windows 10 machine also use Powershell version 3?

Comment: The Windows 10 machine uses Powershell version 5.1. The version difference may or may not explain the difference in their working, but I mainly need to know the proper way to make `Get-AppxPackageManifest` work on the Windows 8 machine.

Comment: Thanks for information

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to make the statement in my question work (Getting all the details using `PackageFullName`)-

```
Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package $(Get-AppxPackage | where PackageFullName -eq "Microsoft.ZuneVideo_1.0.927.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe") | Select -Property *
```

And if you have the `Name` of the app (instead of `PackageFullName`) then you can do the following-

```
Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package $(Get-AppxPackage -Name "Microsoft.ZuneVideo") | Select -Property *
```